# Confusing list behaviour

Tags: python, list

I was experimenting with lists in python and found the following confusing.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> A = [a]*3
>>> A
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> a[2] = 45
>>> 
>>> A
[[1, 2, 45, 4], [1, 2, 45, 4], [1, 2, 45, 4]]
>>> A = a * 3
>>> A
[1, 2, 45, 4, 1, 2, 45, 4, 1, 2, 45, 4]
>>> a[2] = 3
>>> A
[1, 2, 45, 4, 1, 2, 45, 4, 1, 2, 45, 4]
```

First, I multiplied like this: `A = [a]*3` and changed an element of `a`. `A` changed because it contained 3 references of `a`. Then, I multiplied like this: `A = a*3` and changed the same element of `a`. Now, why did `A` not change, assuming that it contained 3 references of `a`, too?

Comment: `a` is a list. Do you see any lists in the second `A`?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the correct duplicate... On the last line, `A` is no longer three references of `[a]`

Comment: Right, that's the "normal" usage of `list * int`.